# WPF Datagrid complex row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I would like to make a repeatable row that would have multiples fields.

exemple

```
=======================================
Attribute 1 [ textbox            ] Date [datePicker]
Attribute 2 [textbox             ] ComboBox
=========================================
Attribute 1 [ textbox            ] Date [datePicker]
Attribute 2 [textbox             ] ComboBox
```

I want to be able to repeat a multirow element. The best for me would be a Datagrid row template modified structure. If you have any other ideas that would be great :)

What would be the best way to go with such a situation?

Thank you for your help!

Charles

Comment: I've found a way to do this with this tutorial, http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/ ,Any other options on how to achieve this? Thank you! - Charles

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML of what you already tried, and explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: The way posted in my last comment is working but I was looking if there are more answers to my question/ other ways to achieve the same goal. I don't have enough reputation to post my comment as an answer before it has 8 hours :/